# KeyCode returns undefined when function is bound to the class react

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to check for the user hitting enter and if they do submit the form. However if the form is bound then keyCode returns undefined, and I believe I need to bind the form in-order to access the refs one of which is a ref to the form which needs to be submitted. Here is my current code...

```
class ChatInput extends React.PureComponent {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.onKeyDown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this)
}

onKeyDown(e) {
    var textarea = this.refs['chat_input'];
    var chatForm = this.refs['chat_form'];

    console.log(code);

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 13) {
        console.log('submit the form here');
    }

}

render() {
    return(
        <form ref="chat_form" className="chat-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
            <fieldset>
                <textarea ref="chat_input" required name="chat_input" onKeyPress={this.onKeyDown} placeholder={`${ !this.props.parentId ? 'Type your message...' : 'Reply to thread...' }`}></textarea>
                <button type="submit"><i className="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the ref ? why not just call `handleSubmit()` on 'enter' ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Think I'm just having one of those days today, looked at this code for ages before submitting it here and it was the console log in the wrong position -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console.log of code is before the assignment, otherwise it seems to work : https://codesandbox.io/s/vjpvr5jxpl

Answer (score 1):

You're code works. you are logging an unassigned variable (you assign to it later). this will work:

```
onKeyDown(e) {
    var textarea = this.refs['chat_input'];
    var chatForm = this.refs['chat_form'];

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    console.log(code);

    if (code === 13) {
        console.log('submit the form here');
    }

}
```